# I have a hw question that I cant find the error to as I am able to print. Someone able to assist me?

Tags: python

```
data = [
    ['Video A','500'],
    ['Video B','300'],
    ['Video C','1000']
]

result = 0

for index in data:
    title = index[0]
    views = index[1]

    if title == 'Video' :
         result += views

print(result)
```

When I run print I keep getting 0. Answer should be 1800. Problem is there's no error and I can't find the part where I made a mistake.

Comment: The titles are `Video A`, `Video B`, and `Video C`.  None of those are equal to `Video`.

Answer (score 4):

seems like you want to check if the title *Starts with* `"Video"`.

also, your views are a string and need to be cast to an integer.

try this:

```py
data = [
    ['Video A', '500'],
    ['Video B', '300'],
    ['Video C', '1000']
]

result = 0

for index in data:
    title = index[0]
    views = index[1]

    if title.startswith('Video'):
        result += int(views)

print(result)
```

Comment: Should you add that `startswith` is case-sensitive?

Comment: or just change values to ints in the table: `500` instead of `'500'`

Answer (score 0):

Right code:

```py
data = [
    ['Video A','500'],
    ['Video B','300'],
    ['Video C','1000']
]

result = 0

for index in data:
    title = index[0]
    views = index[1]

    #you can use
    #if title[:len("Video")] == 'Video':
    #or
    #if title.startswith('Video'):
         result += int(views)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split` :

```py
data =
    ['Video A','500'],
    ['Video B','300'],
    ['Video C','1000']
]

result = 0

for index in data:
    title = index[0]
    views = index[1]

    if title.split(' ',1)[0] == 'Video' :
         result += int(views)

print(result)
```

It allows you to ensure that there's a space after the `'Video'`, and also to have access to the rest of the name:

```
v = "Video A and B"
l = v.split(" ",1)
l[0] # 'Video'
l[1] # 'A and B'
```